# iTunes Match: download on mobile device

Tags: itunes, ios, music, itunes-match

I am considering buying and using iTunes Match. Is it possible to configure which songs will be available as a cached download on my mobile devices? It so, how? As a smart playlist or via "download me" clicks on the songs?

I use my iPhone to play songs while I commute and I do not want to waste gigabytes of mobile traffic on streaming songs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tap on a download icon will download an entire playlist of songs onto the local storage of the device. It doesn't matter if the playlist is a normal one or a smart playlist or a genius mix that you assemble on the go. You can also download albums, individual songs, everything by one artist, etc...

Furthermore, You can easily toggle between showing all songs and just the downloaded songs to check before a trip if you want to grab more songs for offline play. The toggle is also nice when you want cellular data on, but want to avoid accidentally streaming more music from the cloud.

I see no reason why worrying about data caps or cost would hold you back from getting match.

Comment: It's worth highlighting the fact that Match streaming on cellular data must be explicitly turned on: you don't have to worry about Match automatically eating your data allowance.

Comment: @DanJ true - you can edit at in if you wish. I'll add it once I get back to a device with cellular data - hard to recall where it is on this iPad that lacks cellular...

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. One detail left: Is deleting downloaded songs as easy as downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a smart playlist and download the songs in it. I don't think it is dynamic, i.e. you have to tap the iTunes/iCloud icon at rhe bottom of the playlist to download any songs that were newly added to the playlist.